# Dash : Get column value in selected table

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have an application dash with a dash_table.DataTable that I can select to generate some graph. For info it look like that :

[image]

What I need to build the graph is the value in StrategyId of the selected rows. Currently my endpoint looks like that :

```
@app.callback(
    Output('my_figure', 'figure'),
    [Input('my_table', 'selected_rows'),
     Input('monitoring_strategies_table', 'data')]
)
def my_callback(srows, mdata):
    columns = mdata[srows[0]]['StrategyId']
    # function continue here
```

As you can see, I pass as argument the whole data of the table, and the number of the selected rows, then I use that to access the StrategyId.

It works, but I find it pretty big just to get one value (I don't need to pass the whole data of the table, and it can be big, so don't know if it can have bad performance on long run).

So question is simple : is there a way to pass directly as input the value of the column StrategyId?

or at least just the data of the row selected, without passing the whole data of the table ?

Thanks